# Home button in PowerPoint to show on mouseover using VBA

Tags: hyperlink, hover, powerpoint, mouseover

I use a home button on most of my slides with a link back to the agenda for quick jumps during my presentation. That way I avoid flipping through the individual slides and get straight back to the overview.

However, I don't want the home button in my lower right corner to show on each page as it spoils the clean look. I tried to use the mouseover event in combination with a macro but can't get it to run. I thought about making the home button completely transparent and on mouseover I would set the transparency to zero so the button shows up. When I click on it, it would follow the link.

Any help to get me there is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You do know that you can simply press 1 then Enter to return to the first slide in the show, right?

But to follow up on your "I thought about .." idea, why not add a shape on the slide master in a place that won't get covered up by content in any of the slides, then assign it a Go To Slide 1 action setting.  After testing to make sure it does what you want, give it any color you like then make it 99% transparent.

As long as you don't forget where to click, you're good to go.